# Getting data from JTextField that is one of several local variables

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, parseint, absolutelayout

So I am reading a file and I get the amount of lines in that file. Based on that I generate my interface. Now I need to have the ability to edit valus trougth UI . Rows is the variable that has how lines the input document has . Of course the code below doesnt work . I want to write new values to the array from which i read .

```
for(int i=0;i<Rows;i++)
{
    //System.out.println("!"+Symbol[1]+"!");
    //if(Symbol[i]!=""&&Symbol[i]!=null)
    // {
    JTextField symbol = new JTextField(6);
    symbol.setText(Symbol[i]);
    symbol.setBounds(10,25*i+10 , 75, 20);
    symbol.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(symbol);
    JTextField buyf = new JTextField(4);
    buyf.setText(String.valueOf(buy[i]));
    buyf.setBounds(95, 25*i+10, 50, 20);
    buyf.setEditable(true);
    buyf.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() { 
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {  
              buy[i]=Integer.parseInt(buyf.getText());
         }
    });                      
    frame.add(buyf);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want.. but maybe the title of the question is your answer? Don't make them local variables..

Comment: I want to read a file generate UI based on that , and be able to use JTextFields for input

Comment: The description of your problem is not clear... Anyway, the 'buyf' variable has to be declared as final if you want to use it in you anonymous inner class.

Comment: I want to generate a certain number of JTextFields at runtime based on input file and then write values from those JTextFields into an Array where each JTextField is connected to one and only one cell in that array . That array is public .

Comment: Please respect the java coding conventions. It looks like you have a variable named `symbol` and one named `Symbol`

Answer (score 3):

1. don't use [AbsoluteLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) e.g. `symbol.setBounds(10,25*i+10 , 75, 20);` use proper `LayoutManager`, maybe [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is best for your ...
2. use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for listening of changes in [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
3. use [JFormattedTextField with Number formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), rather than plain [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), then you can remove everything about `parseWhatever`
4. you can to use plain [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) but with `DocumentFilter` (remove non numberic chars)
5. [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) could be correct `Listener` an alternative is `DocumentListener` in point second
6. for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), but I think that `DocumentListener` can solve that