# Creating a number of JTextField s that is defined by user input in way to to read text from all of them in a push of a button

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton, jtextfield

I used to make my UI by making declaring new `JTextField` in a for cycle while attaching an action listener by anon class to each `JTextField`, which means that you have to press enter fire an event which will read the text of the field and put it into an array here is the code 
[Getting data from JTextField that is one of several local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639162/getting-data-from-jtextfield-that-is-one-of-several-local-variables) without a few minor changes . Now I have to modify it to so that i press a button like Apply in order to have values written into an array. While I found two ways to do this wonder what is the optimal way to do this .

1. The horrible way . Create an array that acts as temporary storage ,
   replace `ActionListener`s with `DocumentListener`s that will place
   the values into this temp array . And a button that will on press
   iterate through the the temp array placing its values into the
   target array.
2. A better way which I found while searching , create a `JTextField`
   array as public and simply have a button that will on press iterate
   through the `JTextField` array and place its values into the target
   array.

Comment: Well, that's nice...and what's the question?

Comment: is there a better way to do this ? or any other at all(sane) ?

Answer (score 4):

[`Adder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513) is an example that maintains a `List<JFormattedTextField>` to enforce formatting. It uses a `PropertyChangeListener` & `FocusListener` to update on navigation events, such as the default [key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-Tab</kbd>.

[image]